# How can I link an icon with a record but display it away from the record partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, icons

Hello I'm super new to programming and cant figure a way of accomplishing this,

I currently have a table of venue records and each is being displayed as a partial on the index page. I would like for each venue to have an icon which displays on a map I have on one side of the screen. The map is just a div with a background image.

How can each venue have its own icon which is placed on the map by absolute positioning? but only displays when its associated venue is display as the venue results can be filtered.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this with this bit of jQuery in the venue partial html.erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px";
</script>
```

I added iconleftpx:integer and icontoppx:integer fields to the venue table which populate the top and left values for the absolute positioning called by the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield and content_for.  These will allow you to populate a separate part of the page with data from partials.